# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat - Tuesday 7 Feb 23:00 UTC / 6pm EST

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary. (:

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Tuesday the 7th at 23:00 UTC / 6:00pm EST**

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=2&day=07&year=2012&hour=23&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/269/gaming-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 6th-8th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=gaming.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: Your reverse smiley confuses me...

Comment: Do we have to invite ALL the candidates?  That could be... distracting.

Comment: It's possible I won't be able to arrive at 7 due to my class schedule. Hopefully I will be able to be there though.

Comment: @Wipqozn It's at 6, not 7. Unless you're in a different timezone, in which case... nevermind. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Different timezone :P

Comment: I won't be able to attend this evening, but I will answer the questions after the fact :)  If you'd like to have some time to talk to me, come find me on chat and I'd love to discuss whatever's on your mind.

Comment: Is compiling the Q and As into posts here a bad idea?

Comment: @NickT Usually Tim Stone or Rebecca does this, with a script that automates a lot of the grunt work. [Like this.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2508/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest) I don't know why Gaming's digest isn't up yet.